# How add a table as header on each page with jsPDF and autoTable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I will have a flexible table on the pdf... so if it is very big, autoTable will split it in different pages... right? In that point, if the table will be splitted in different pages, I want to put a table AS HEADER on each page...

I tried the hooks **beforePageContent** & **autoTableAddPageContent** but I couldn't make it work... I'm calling doc.autoTable inside:

```
let columns = [
  {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
  {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"},
  {title: "Email", dataKey: "email"}
];

let data = [
  {id: 1, name: "A", email: "email@host.com"}, 
  {id: 2, name: "B", email: "email@host.com"}
];

let options = { startY: 30 };

doc.autoTable(columns, data, options);
```

What options do I have?

I had use jsPDF with autoTable so know the basics

Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by repeat? The same table on each page?

Comment: Yes. If I need to put that table on each page before the content

Answer (score 0):

I you want to add a table on each page you can simply call `doc.autoTable` multiple times. Here is a simple example:

```js
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
var headers = ["Header 1", "Header 2"];
var rows = [["Cell 1", "Cell 2"], ["Cell 1", "Cell 2"]];

doc.autoTable(headers, rows);
doc.text("Some content...", 40, doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 40);

doc.addPage();

doc.autoTable(headers, rows);
doc.text("Some content...", 40, doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 40);


doc.save("table.pdf");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.1.0/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

Comment: But my data size is flexible and it can have 1 row or 500.. so I don't know know many pages it will have... shouldn't it be auto?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the data is flexible. Have you tried the above?

Comment: Yes, but I can't. When I should call doc.addPage() ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You want two tables on each page? Why did beforePageContent not work?

Comment: Yeah, I think we are not understanding hehe

I will have a flexible table on the pdf... so if it is very big, autoTable will split it in different pages... right? In that point, if the table will be splitted in different pages, I want to put a table AS HEADER on each page...

Comment: Update your question with the info requested above and I'll take a look again. Also, show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

To show table headers on each page using jsPDF-Autotable, we can use below option.

```
showHead: 'everyPage'
```

Official jsPDF-AutoTable documentation link
https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#other-options